# Is it possible to enable bootloader unlocking on C6603 (Yuga/Sony Xperia Z)?

Tags: bootloader-lock, sony-xperia-z

I was following [Sony's official guide for unlocking the bootloader](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/instructions). However, upon entering `*#*#7378423#*#*` into the phone App and navigating to `Service Info -> Configuration` under the Rooting Status category, it said `Bootloader unlock allowed: No`

I tried Googling on how to solve the issue, but I mostly hit dead-ends. A few of the guides claimed that flashing a stock ROM would work, but it was often met with negative feedback from other readers. There are apparently some paid services that do this, too, but I'm not in the position to resort to them. Some people said it's virtually impossible to do it.

The main reason why I want to flash the ROM is because my operator/carrier (T-Mobile) has loaded the phone with bloatware *and* there's this one application that just *keeps* giving me grief with notifications. Also, I've grown very familiar with Cyanogenmod with my previous phone, and I miss it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not in this case, you are seriously out of luck!

It cannot be done.

If it did say "Bootloader unlock allowed: Yes", then by all means go for it.

Comment: Well, this is a grievance! Can I at least flash the stock C6603 ROM (safely) without all the T-Mobile bloatware?

Answer (score 2):

You can flash a stock Sony rom on to your device by using flash tool just Google it, then you  find a stock ftf rom and you can flash it without unlocking the bootloader.

Comment: Even if the Bootloader *can't* be unlocked (nevermind it being locked in the first place). Also, I'm curious whether this will break Bravia II? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use SeeTool box it's the solution for an Experia bootloader unlock. All the videos on YouTube to unlock bootloader are for movil with YES.

Comment: What does "All the videos on YouTube to unlock bootloader are for movil with YES." mean? And could you post a link to the program you talk about?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But you need to sim unlock your phone first. Do that and the bootloader unlock allowed will turn to yes. then pay for a bootloader unlock code or try to get one from the sony site once again. It should all work.

Answer (score -1):

Got unlock code from safeunlockcode .com within an hour, and could successfully unlock my Sony Xperia Z on the first attempt. This, after even Sony Xperia Z customer care couldn't find an unlock code for my device since apparently, my mobile's IMEI number was not in their system!

Comment: Unlocking the bootloader is nothing to do with getting a SIM unlock code from your carrier. SIM-unlocking the phone allows it to be used with a different carrier. Unlocking the bootloader allows unofficial ROMs to be used.